# qt simple browser with flash enabled

Tags: c++, qt, flash

I am using the simple browser example and trying to add the flash player from my source folder instead of using the one from my computer.

I have modified the code as per the [document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#pepper-plugin-api)

in my main.cpp before creating the QApplication I do the following:

```
argc = 3;
argv[1] = "--ppapi-flash-path=./PepperFlashPlayer/libpepflashplayer.so";
argv[2] = "--ppapi-flash-version=26.0.0.151";

QApplication app(argc, argv);
QWebEngineSettings::defaultSettings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

This works fine for Linux and flash loads from my source folder (I made sure of this by removing flash .so file from my linux)

BUT my problem is on mac when I do

```
argc = 3;
argv[1] = "--ppapi-flash-path=./PepperFlashPlayer/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin";
argv[2] = "--ppapi-flash-version=26.0.0.151";

QApplication app(argc, argv);
QWebEngineSettings::defaultSettings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

This does not load flash at all - I use this [URL](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) to check.

I have both the .plugin and .so in the PepperFlashPlayer folder in my source folder where main.cpp and the .pro files are.

What else do I need to do?

**NOTE** It does not even load the default flash player located at

```
/Library/Internet \Plug-Ins/PepperFlashPlayer/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin
```